# Заголовочный файл для программирования протокола MRIM на С++

Tags: сеть, email, клиент, c++

На официальном сайте Mail.ru Agent'a, приводится ссылка на заголовочный файл для программирования использую MRIM. Он, кстати, вот [здесь](http://agent.mail.ru/ru/proto.h).

Я скопировал это, сунул в текстовый редактор, а помимо того, что какая-то проблема с форматом (там UNICOD), ещё и копируется всё в одну строчку вперемешку с комментариями. В итоге приходится все самому расставлять. Это очень долго, и я решил спросить - может кто пробовал заниматься написанием майл агента или просто знает, где скачать заголовочный файл. Помогите, пожалуйста, с поиском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я файл скачал с помощью wget'а и получил вполне ASCII. Что я делаю не так? Может попробуете скачать другим способом?

Comment: С созданием заголовочного файла теперь проблем нет. Но есть другая проблема - при построении решения проекта, выводится куча ошибок, которые в этом заголовочном файле.

Comment: Пример вывода сообщений об ошибках. Плиз.

Comment: (1) : error C2014: команда препроцессора не должна начинаться с пробела
(2) : error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "status"
(2) : error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается (2) : error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "константа"
(2) : error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается (2) : error C2014: команда препроцессора не должна начинаться с (3) (11) : error C2014: команда препроцессора не должна начинаться с пробела
(13) : error C2014: команда препроцессора не должна начинаться с пробела
Это примерно 1/15.

Comment: Тогда возьмите http://code.google.com/p/mrim-prpl/source/browse/